# WPF DataGrid with TreeView type hierarchy

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, hierarchical-data

Is it possible to have a pure hierarchical wpf data grid? Now there are 3 possible solutions dicussed over the internet ...

1. GroupStyle
2. TreeListView instead of DataGrid
3. RowDetailsTemplate

Now all 3 are not useful in my case as they each have limitations.

`GroupStyle` provides grouped row presenters but their parent is simply `GroupItem`. This is where my data source is different. In my case the parent of the grouped items will be of the same type of item.

e.g. `Folder` class has `List<Folders> children`. So the parent of child folders is of type `Folder` itself.

`RowDetailsTemplate` would need me to host another datagrid that is bound to `Children`, but that would mean it would have its own column headers and what I want is the children to **share** the same column view of the parent DataGrid, just like they do in `TreeListView`.

And for `TreeListView`, thats what I am using right now, but its problem is ...

It looses virtualization and **it is not a datagrid**

:-)

I was thinking like some attached behavior that toggles the hierarchy view for the data grid like...

```
  <DataGrid HierarchicalBehavior.HierarchyPath="Children" ... />
```

Where `Children` is a property of type `IEnumerable` under each item.

I hope you guys understand what I am getting at.

Any ideas?

Comment: And why are you not using other data grids? Infragistics / telerik / Xceed / DevXpress etc.? Funds?

Comment: Yes precisely the same reason. WPF datagrid is part of .Net 4.0 framework, so basically its free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could implement this finally. The code is too big to post. But if anyone's looking for the solution, do send an email to me.

Bascially I did the following things...

1. I used the quick flattening of hierarchy of item into flat list.
2. Each item bound to the WPF data grid I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and also    following extra properties via a base class ..

**Parent** => Parent item which this item is child for. Readonly.

**HasHierarchy** => False when hierarchy children is null or empty. Writeable.

**IsItemVisible** => Current Visibility. Writeable.

**IsBranchVisible** => False if any ancestor has IsExpanded = false or IsItemVisible = false. ReadOnly but notifyable.

**IsExpanded** => If the item is expanded. Writeable.

```
3. I put a PLINQ call to filter the `IsBranchVisible` property as true, of all children whenever any descenden's `IsExpanded` property is **toggled**.
```

Voala! It works like charm. Fast due to PLINQ.

Comment: Your solution is awesome. Unfortunately don't know your email address