# WPF: ListView as treeview (with GroupItem)

Tags: wpf, listview, treeview

Is there a way to render a ListView (using Group Item) as a treeview? Maybe hierarchical template can be useful.

BTW, which WPF control was it build (TreeView or ListView)?:

[Undefined Control](http://citilab.webcindario.com/control.gif)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx) is what you may be lookking for. Although there is another similar thread awating reply... [WPF DataGrid with TreeView type hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739178/wpf-datagrid-with-treeview-type-hierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

I believe is a TreeView(Custom One) if you would like to see an example of treeView see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045742/implement-wpf-treeview-with-different-parent-nodes-a-well-as-different-child-nod)... thread..